# What other discrete non-trivial non-Clifford groups of gates are there?

Tags: quantum-gate, clifford-group

I do not know many groups (as in group theory) of quantum gates. Aside from trivial ones, I know there is Pauli group and the Clifford group. Recently I discovered another interesting group generated by $\sqrt{X}$ and controlled-$\sqrt{X}$ (NCV library). There is also the NOT, CNOT, Toffoli (NCT library).

What examples of groups that are

- discrete,
- have two or more generators,
- are not the same as the groups listed above but with a different Pauli gate,
- have at least a non-Clifford gate, and
- are not considered a universal gate set (like $\{H,T,\mathrm{CNOT}\}$)

are there?

Comment: Google's Sycamore uses the roots of Pauli gates (along with $W=(X+Y)/\sqrt 2$) as single-qubit gates, and a modified $\mathsf{iSWAP}$ as a two-qubit gate.  See [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/understanding-googles-quantum-supremacy-using-a-programmable-superconducting-p) and also [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/8337/understanding-googles-quantum-supremacy-using-a-programmable-superconducting-p)

Comment: @MarkS I meant a group as in group theory, what is the group there? isnt that clifford+non-cliffod=universal

Comment: See here https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/2036/why-are-quantum-gates-unitary-and-not-special-unitary

Comment: @MarkS are you pointing to (special) unitary groups? That is not discrete.

Comment: Would you consider a discrete universal gateset trivial? If not you have ofc e.g. $\{H, T, CNOT\}$

Comment: @Mauricio sorry I missed that part of the question

Comment: If you consider the Cliffords to be finite, (basically by removing its center $U(1)$), then I _think_ every set of the Clifford Hierarchy is also finite.

Comment: @JSdJ good point. I guess I am looking for sets that do not form a universal gate set. Also I am not considering  necessarily finite sets.

Comment: Every finite group occurs as a subgroup of a unitary group. Any faithful representation of it gives an embedding. I think you mean to add more restrictions (contain non trivial subgroup of Paulis?....)

Comment: @unknown not necessarily finite groups, also must include a non-Clifford gate so it cannot be a subgroup of Pauli

Comment: @Mauricio I said *contain" a subgroup of Paulis...